# How to detect in J2EE that request comes from iframe?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I need to block\allow some requests to my app (depending on origin of request) if it is being embedded into an iframe. 
Is there a header that might be of service in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can forbid a page from being included in a frame on modern browsers with a http header of `X-Frame-Options DENY` or `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN`. Aside from that, you can't detect if a page is in a frame or not server side.  You can check client side in js: `window.self !== window.top`

If you're trying to prevent click jacking, the suggested method is with nounce.

Comment: So, there is no request attribute\header available that will tell me that request comes from iframe... Hmmm.. interesting